# regex expression in jinja2

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2

I have a jinja2 script with a for loop, I just want to see if there is any way I can use regex checks in an if statement.
So the script looks like:

```
{% for key, value in notes.items() -%}
if {{ value }} starts with http or https
then ~*^/{{ key }}(\?.*)?$ {{ value }};
otherwise
~*^/{{ key }}(\?.*)?$ /{{ value }};
{% endfor %}
```

Is that somewhow writable???

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Put an example of *dict* and the expected result. Rename `dict`. It is a reserved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    _dict:
      k1: v1
      k2: https://example.com
      k3: http://example.com
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for key, value in _dict.items() -%}
          {% if value is regex('^(http|https).*$') %}
          ~*^/{{ key }}(\?.*)?$ {{ value }};
          {% else %}
          ~*^/{{ key }}(\?.*)?$ /{{ value }};
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    ~*^/k1(\?.*)?$ /v1;
    ~*^/k2(\?.*)?$ https://example.com;
    ~*^/k3(\?.*)?$ http://example.com;
```

---

**Notes**

Q: ***"No test named 'regex' found."***

See [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings). The test *match* gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for key, value in _dict.items() -%}
          {% if value is match('(http|https)') %}
          ~*^/{{ key }}(\?.*)?$ {{ value }};
          {% else %}
          ~*^/{{ key }}(\?.*)?$ /{{ value }};
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Q: ***"The same result with 'match' and 'search'."***

A: Test the first 4 characters of the value

```yaml
         {% if value[:4] == 'http' %}
```

Comment: No test named 'regex' found. Also tried with regex_search! same!

Comment: Read the link. Try *match*.

Comment: unfortunately it gives the same result with match and search

Comment: Im using Jinja2 3.1.2

Comment: It's even newer than I have (jinja version = 3.0.1), but the tests are about Ansible (my version ansible [core 2.12.9]). The simple comparison of the strings should work too. I added an example.